# Is it possible for blending modes to be applied to text in css/javascript/canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas

I would prefer CSS purely with a fall back to Javascript.  If not possible at all how could i apply this effect using Canvas tags?

Heres the desired effect:  it's a bunch of `difference` blending modes on top of another.
[image: Text blending modes]

if so, is it possible to make work on Mozilla?

Answer (score 1):

Just thoughts on the possibilities...

**A pure CSS solution would be spotty as far as browser support.**

*Filter effects*

Some browsers support CSS image filter effects.

You could use the invert-filter to flip black/white.

*Non-rectangular shapes*

Some browsers support CSS shaping and/or CSS clip-path.

You could use those to define your non-rectangular areas on which to apply the invert filter.

**Alternatively**

1. You could have 2 images for the 2 modes: black-on-white and white-on-black.
2. You could use Canvas to combine clipping paths, getImageData and compositing to invert your colors.
3. You could draw your text with SVG.  You can use clipping to isolate your b/w vs w/b regions and use the feColorMatrix to invert the colors

Example SVG feColorMatrix:

```
<filter id="matrix-invert">
    <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="-1 0 0 0 1 0 -1 0 0 1 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0"/>
 </filter>
```